# Meteor insert trouble

Tags: mongodb, templates, meteor, client

I do a simple insert with this template.

```
<template name="device_register">
<form class="device_register-form">
    <input class="device_register_serial" name="device_register_serial" type="text" placeholder="Serial Number" />
    <div class="button button-block button-stable register_device_button">
                    <i class=".register_device_button">Register</i> 
    </div>
</form>
```

and using this coffee script :

```
  Template.device_register.onCreated ->
  @autorun =>
    if Meteor.isCordova
      if Session.get('connected')
        @subscribe 'userData'
    else
      @subscribe 'userData'


Template.device_register.events
  'click .register_device_button': (event, template) ->
    serial = document.getElementsByClassName('device_register_serial')[0].value
    @subscribe 'DeviceAvailable', serial,
     onReady: () =>
        alpha = DeviceAvailable.insert({serial: "azerty1234", firmware_version : 1.00})
        if not _.isEmpty(alpha)
            sAlert.info alpha
```

an id is displayed with sAlert but nothing add in the collection. And I don't understand why.

Comment: I tried to use the code you provided but `@subscribe` leads to an error on the client side: `this.subscribe is not a function`.  The value of `this` in an event handler is the data context.  Are you really getting the alert with the code that you've shown?  Also, where are you looking to check the collection, on the client or server side?

Answer (score -1):

In fact, You can,t use the subscribe function in an event, you need to call a Method on the Server side.

```
     Meteor.call('functionName', arg, function(error, data){
})
```

and on the server side

```
        Meteor.methods({
        fuctionName:function(param) {
//your code
    })
```

Comment: That isn't true.  You *can* use subscribe in the event, you just can't use `this.subscribe` because `this` refers to the data context.  Use `Meteor.subscribe`.